# How to end all running excel macros and excel functions?

Tags: excel, function, testing, macros, nested

I currently have a main excel macro which calls a bunch of functions. Basically:

```
Sub main()
    'Long code
    Call init
End Sub

Private Function init()
    'Long Code
End Function
```

Some of these pieces of code are quite long and take some time to process, which is not great because I am constantly testing pieces of the code here and there.

I know that pressing esc multiple times ends an excel macro, and clumping all my code into the main Sub main() works fine. So my two questions are:

1. If I call a function from my main sub, will the main sub continue to run, or will it wait for a return signal from the function?
2. Is there a way for me to halt all subs and functions with one keypress? Currently, it seems that although the main sub ends when I spam esc, the function which has been called keeps running.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL + Break will stop any running loops.

The main sub will wait for the return value from another function unless you run it asynchronously.

EDIT:
Misleading VBA does not support asynchronous programming.

Comment: Should note on an infinite loop I have found if I don't CTRL + Break quick enough after the application become unresponsive it does not always work.

Comment: I don't believe my keyboard has a Break key, what is the alternative?

Comment: As for the second point, I always start by running my Sub main macro. All the functions are called from that sub, so will the sub wait at that "Call init" line until init finishes running, regardless of if it is expected to return a variable or not?

Comment: On my keyboard the Pause and Break key are the same if you tell me the make and model of your laptop and keyboard I can figure it out for you.

Comment: It will run each line one by one, when it gets to a function it will leave the Sub Main perform the actions in the function and once they are all complete perform the next line in the Sub Main. If you want both the code in the sub main and the code in the functions to run concurrently you should call the functions async. I have never had a need to do this in excel and I just looked into it does not look like it is possible natively  in VBA.

Comment: I am currently using this mouse [link](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823129038)

Comment: As per your second point, that makes perfect sense. I suppose the issue with my code is that its not stopping completely, not that its running async. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Try the pause button to the right of your NUM light.

Comment: If you show some of the code myself or someone else may be able to point out what is happening. But if you are doing something like string = function() it will not go to the next line until string is assigned.

Comment: Ah, got it figured out! It was more of a runtime thing, I kept pressing run while the program was still running the previous time, so it gave me a bunch of odd outputs and debug prompts. That key you mentioned works perfectly. Cheers!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132548/discussion-between-richard-yang-and-shane-burke).